# How to properly map an Array of name and type to an Array of StructField

Tags: scala, apache-spark

the simple problem I have is this:

```
val t = StructField("attName", DecimalType,true)

type mismatch, expected: DataType, actual: DecimalType.type
```

I want to create a case class which can be useful to automatically generate an array of structField. So I begin to try this.

```
case class MyClass1(attributeName: String, attributeType: DataType)
```

In order to create my test1:

```
val test1 = Array(
  MyClass1("att1", StringType),
  MyClass1("att2", IntegerType),
  MyClass1("att3", DecimalType)
)
```

This is wrong because the third line with DecimalType thrown an error. (DecimalType is not a DataType). So I tried with a second case class like this.

```
case class MyClass2[T](attributeName: String, attributeType: T)

val test2 = Array(
  MyClass2("att1", StringType),
  MyClass2("att2", IntegerType),
  MyClass2("att3", DecimalType)
)
```

Now this is ok but lines below does not work  because Decimal is not a DataType.

```
val myStruct = test2.map(x =>
  StructField(x.attributeName,x.attributeType, true)
)
```

So here is my question. How to create a StructField with DecimalType and do you think my caseclass is a good approach? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DecimalType` is not a singleton - it has to be initialized with a given precision and scale:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{DataType, DecimalType}

DecimalType(38, 10): DataType
```

```
org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType = DecimalType(38,10)
```

That being said `StructField` is already a case class and provides default arguments for `nullable` (`true`) and `metadata` so another representation seems superfluous.